# Download files from an S3 folder in Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon SDK using Swift but want to download all the files from a folder in a bucket.

The best way at the moment I can do this is by listing all the files within my folder:

```
    let listRequest: AWSS3ListObjectsRequest = AWSS3ListObjectsRequest()
    let s3 = AWSS3.s3(forKey: AWSServiceClientKey)
    listRequest.bucket = AWSBucketName
    listRequest.prefix = AWSBundleName
    s3.listObjects(listRequest).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject? in
        let listObjectsOutput = task.result;
        for object in (listObjectsOutput?.contents)! {
            print(object.key)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Then for each of these I will create a URL to download from Amazon S3 doing something like:

```
    let expression = AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadExpression()

    var completionHandler: AWSS3TransferUtilityDownloadCompletionHandlerBlock?
    completionHandler = { (task, URL, data, error) -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            var downloadFileURL = self.getURL(for: .applicationSupportDirectory)
            downloadFileURL = downloadFileURL!.appendingPathComponent("component.txt")
            try? data?.write(to: downloadFileURL!)
        })
    }

    let transferUtility = AWSS3TransferUtility.default()

    transferUtility.downloadData(
        fromBucket: bucketname,
        key: fileName,
        expression: expression,
        completionHandler: completionHandler
        ).continueWith {
            (task) -> AnyObject? in if let error = task.error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

            if let _ = task.result {
                // Do something with downloadTask.

            }
            return nil;
    }
```

Is there a way to combine these operations so that I can download all the files from a folder in a single step?

Comment: Do you mean to write a function that does all this?

Comment: No. I think there should be something about a prefix somewhere so only objects from a single folder are downloaded which could be done in a single function (with single responsibility). Source: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-download-a-folder-from-AWS-S3